# TS2322: not the good type

Tags: angular, typescript

I followed an msal, angular tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

This part of the code seem to be the problem

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: !isIframe ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

When i do

```
npm start
```

I get this error

> TS2322: Type '"disabled" | "en abled"' is not assignable to type
> 'InitialNavigation | undefined'.   Type '"enabled"' is not assignable
> to type 'InitialNavigation | undefined'.

When i click on **initialNavigation**, i see

```
/**
 * One of `enabled`, `enabledBlocking`, `enabledNonBlocking` or `disabled`.
 * When set to `enabled` or `enabledBlocking`, the initial navigation starts before the root
 * component is created. The bootstrap is blocked until the initial navigation is complete. This
 * value is required for [server-side rendering](guide/universal) to work. When set to
 * `enabledNonBlocking`, the initial navigation starts after the root component has been created.
 * The bootstrap is not blocked on the completion of the initial navigation. When set to
 * `disabled`, the initial navigation is not performed. The location listener is set up before the
 * root component gets created. Use if there is a reason to have more control over when the router
 * starts its initial navigation due to some complex initialization logic.
 */
initialNavigation?: InitialNavigation;
```

Comment: `"en abled"'`, with a space, in the error message? Something fishy going on there.

Comment: carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/InitialNavigation), type `InitialNavigation` can be assigned one of the following values: `'disabled'`, `'enabledBlocking'`, or `'enabledNonBlocking'`.

*`type InitialNavigation = 'disabled' | 'enabledBlocking' | 'enabledNonBlocking';`*

Where `enabledNonBlocking` is the default behaviour.

Comment: strange i see enabled when i click on the value... but in your link enabled don't exist